# Woocommerce Allow to edit only specific fields on products editor page for a specific role

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, permissions

I want to create a new user role and it should only be able to edit selected fields on the product editor page. Is there a way to achieve that?

**Edit:**

I don't need to hide the fields from the products editor page. I just need to add checks in the back-end code so that only specific fields are allowed to be saved when the product is updated.

Comment: If the fields are woo default fields will require alot of modifications. What i do is hiding fields for specific role with js.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this. I've updated the question add added more information. We can hide fields with js. But still there will not be backend validation. I want to add backend logic when product is being saved so that only specific meta data is saved in the database. Rest of the fields should be ignored when saving. Any ideas? :)

Comment: You can check save_post hook or update_post_meta compare old with new data. You can check who is updating the product and pass only what you want to update.